# Countdown timer restart when it ends

Tags: jquery, countdown

I'm making a simple countdown script to update my users, however i want the script to start again when the timer reaches 0, at this moment the timer is going negative -1, -2, -3, etc..

**HTML**

```
<h5 id="update">Updating your profile in <span>10</span> seconds.</h5>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sec = $('#update span').text()
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        $('#update span').text(--sec);
        if (sec == 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('/user/update') }}",
                type: "GET",
                data: { 'id' : {{ Auth::user()->id }} }
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Thanks,
Tiago

Comment: Just add sec = 10; after ajax. https://jsfiddle.net/o9krfznt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    var sec = $('#update span').text(), secInit = sec;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        $('#update span').text(--sec);
        if (sec == 0) {
            sec = secInit;
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('/user/update') }}",
                type: "GET",
                data: { 'id' : {{ Auth::user()->id }} }
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: @TiagoF glad it helps!

Comment: Can u help me in another thing? i need a progress bar to work with this script, but it need to go countup instead of countdown..